# How to move the scrollbar at the bottom of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

The picture shows a scrollbar at the bottom of my window. I can't figure out how to move it just under the table.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJjuy.png]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        JTable table = new JTable(10, 20);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: The table actually takes the whole window. That is the reason the scrollbar appears at the bottom. That becomes clearer as soon as you add more rows

Comment: If I call table.setPreferredSize() the table shrinks but the scrollbar is still at the bottom.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: That is because the window keeps its size and  and the `ScrollPane` is added to the window. Basically the `ScrollPane` is just a container for the `JTable`. Another part which plays into this (not so much in this example) is the `Layout` you choose. @AndrewThompson the code illustrates his problem (need to replace the variables with `int` values)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew and Baumer

Comment: @XtremeBaumer *"(need to replace the variables with int values)"* For clarity, I don't (and shouldn't) need to replace anything, or add anything. After all, my interest in this is purely academic. You feel free to add or replace anything you like. I'll wait for an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: Is the new code ok?